# SaveXml in php returning empty string

Tags: php

I have the following xml :

```
<assumption_list>
    <assumption name="test" id="23" description="test1" is_shared="no">
        <watchlists>
            <watchlist globalissuer="koolwater" prepayrate="5" prepaytype="CPR" defaultrate="5" defaulttype="CDR" lossrate="7" lagmonths="2"/>
        </watchlists>
    </assumption>
</assumption_list>
```

I load the following received from a jsp call in php as DOMDocument

I am trying the get the `<watchlists>` node as a string by using the following code :

```
$result = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('watchlists');
$strxml='';
foreach($result as $element)
{
    print_r(simplexml_import_dom($element));
    $strxml = $xmlDoc->saveXML($element);
    var_dump($strxml);
}
```

I do see my `print_r(simplexml_import_dom($element));` this getting populated but for some reasons i see the empty string after the saveXml operation. Is there something wrong with the current implementation.

I am trying to get the xml string representation so that i can pass the xml string to c# dll used by php application

Comment: Are you trying to echo the element or save it to a file?

Comment: basically i am trying to grab the watchlists node in a string ,so that i can pass it to c# dll from php

Comment: i realized that i have do a view source to see the actual xml output

Comment: That's caught me out before too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to output the xml string representation, you can use a simple `htmlentities()` on this one. Consider this example: [**Sample Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/mz0Q0y)

```
$xmlDoc = '<assumption_list> <assumption name="test" id="23" description="test1" is_shared="no"> <watchlists> <watchlist globalissuer="koolwater" prepayrate="5" prepaytype="CPR" defaultrate="5" defaulttype="CDR" lossrate="7" lagmonths="2"/> </watchlists> </assumption></assumption_list>';
$xmlDoc = simplexml_load_string($xmlDoc);
$result = $xmlDoc->assumption->watchlists->watchlist;
// echo $result->asXML(); // output as xml
echo htmlentities($result->asXML()); // output as xml string
```